# How can I programmatically remove impersonation in ASP.Net?

Tags: windows, security, asp.net-4.0

I have  in my web.config, is there any way to programmatically "unimpersonate"? There is just one or two little places where I need to not be impersonating... is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old question, I know, but would this do what you're asking?

```
using (System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext wic = 
         System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(IntPtr.Zero))
{
    // code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I'm aware of is to call the Win32 [`RevertToSelf`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.reverttoself) function, do what you need to do outside impersonation, then reinstate your previous identity once you're done.